# Change Keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {1:[9,9,9],2:[8,8,8],3:[7,7,7]}
```

and a list of keys :

```
newkeylist = [4,2,3]
```

Now i want check the keys in the dict with the content in the list. If they are different i want to replace the key in the dict with the one in the list.

```
for i in range(len(newkeylist)):
       if d.key()[i] != newkeylist[i]:
             d.key()[i] = newkeylist[i]
```

Comment: What you have isn't an OrderedDict. Also: why?

Comment: Your question seems to be ambiguous. Please update your question with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
d = {1:[9,9,9],2:[8,8,8],3:[7,7,7]}
newkeylist = [4,2,3]
d_copy = d.copy()
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d_copy.items()):
    if k != newkeylist[i]:
        d[newkeylist[i]] = v
        del d[k]
```

but as @jonrsharpe said, it's not an ordered dict: the output is random